# reverse levels of treenodes

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

In a treenode levels will be increased in ascending order I want to write a function so that it will reverse the level of a tree I know that I should get the depth of the tree and then compute the

`depth-selectednodeLevel`

so that it will result the tree levels in descending order
I didn't know how to get the depth of the tree,the property `LastNode` will give the last child of the node and I coudn't use it for depth because it will return lastNode of just for that level not the lower ones.

for example a usual treenodes levels are as follows

```
|0|
 |
|1|
 |
|2|
 |
|3|
```

I want to make it

```
 |3|
  |
 |2|
  |
 |1|
  |
 |0|
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need to solve the issue is finding the depth of the tree, so to do that you can use simple recursion.

Psuedo-code:

```
int GetDepth(Node node)
{
    return node.HasChilds ? node.Childs.Max(GetDepth) : node.Level;
}
```

And in C#, assuming you use the TreeNode class to represent nodes:

```
public int GetDepth(TreeNode node)
{
    return node.Nodes.Count == 0
        ? node.Level
        : node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Select(this.GetDepth).Max();
}
```

Usage:

```
var depth = GetDepth(myTree.Root);
```

And if you don't have the Level property of every node, you can just add a parameter like so:

```
public int GetDepth(TreeNode node, int depth)
{
    return node.Nodes.Count == 0
        ? depth
        : node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>()
              .Select(x => this.GetDepth(x, depth + 1)).Max();
}
```

Usage:

```
var depth = GetDepth(myTree.Root, 0);
```